esp is recognized as unknow USB device
i am trying to connct an eps32 devkitC that appear in the device manager as a usb device
i try the same usb with the same cable on other pc and it work fine
i have installed silicon labs cp210x usb to uart bridge
the esp32 should appear as a serial port which is not happening so i try install the driver manually but that didn't work since the driver is suitable for serial port not USB so when I try to install the driver manually i got that the best driver for this device is installed
